# PC / tablet ID and a mobile ID - Microsoft advertising ad units

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a uwp app, and I finished it and was preparing to submit my app in the store, through the dev center. My application has `AdControl` advertising, which is presented in the desktop version (Windows 10) and the mobile version (Windows 10 Mobile) through `VisualStateManager`

My `AdControl`: (example)

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab"
         AdUnitId="test"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="250"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="300"/>
```

In the Desktop version I have:

```
<Setter Target="Ad.Height" Value="90"/>
<Setter Target="Ad.Width" Value="728"/>
```

In the Mobile version I have:

```
<Setter Target="Ad.Height" Value="50"/>
<Setter Target="Ad.Width" Value="320"/>
```

That is, the size of the banner adapts to the different screen sizes.

And I have this too:

```
// Declare an AdControl.
private AdControl myAdControl = null;

// Application ID and ad unit ID values for Microsoft advertising. By default,
// assign these to non-mobile ad unit info.
private string myAppId = WAPPLICATIONID;
private string myAdUnitId = WADUNITID;
Add the following code to your Page class constructor, after the call to the InitializeComponent() method.

Copy
C#
myAdGrid.Width = AD_WIDTH;
myAdGrid.Height = AD_HEIGHT;

// For mobile device families, use the mobile ad unit info.
if ("Windows.Mobile" == AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily)
{
    myAppId = MAPPLICATIONID;
    myAdUnitId = MADUNITID;
}

// Initialize the AdControl.
myAdControl = new AdControl();
myAdControl.ApplicationId = myAppId;
myAdControl.AdUnitId = myAdUnitId;
myAdControl.Width = AD_WIDTH;
myAdControl.Height = AD_HEIGHT;
myAdControl.IsAutoRefreshEnabled = true;

myAdGrid.Children.Add(myAdControl);
```

I just have an ad on my main page, where do I put PC / tablet ID and a mobile ID?
Do I have to create two `AdControl`? (One for each device family)

Comment: How is this question different from your question that you have asked 3 days ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189249/microsoft-advertising-ad-units-device-family)